# What am I doing wrong with arrays?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm pretty new to the JavaScript as well as to the Node.JS and I really can't understand why I'm getting **NaN** using the following expression:

```
var aUsersBetted = {};
aUsersBetted['1337'] += 200000;
logger.debug(aUsersBetted['1337']);
```

After doing this it prints me NaN in console. I'm really confused now. Sorry for the dumb question by the way.

Comment: there is no leet element to add on.

Comment: This is an object, not an Array

Comment: If I output the whole array it says: `{ '1337': NaN }`.

Comment: Hint: what is `undefined + 1`? It's not the same as `0 + 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take it line by line.

This `var aUsersBetted = {};` creates an object, not an array.

This `aUsersBetted['1337'] += 200000;` adds 200000 to the value that is associated with the key 1337.

Since, you haven't defined the key before you use it, it's value is also undefined. So you try to add to an undefined value to a number. That's why you get this error.

One possible workaround to your problem it would be to initialize the value of 1337, like:

```
aUsersBetted['1337'] = 0;
```

Then your expression, `aUsersBetted['1337'] += 200000;`, would add 200000 to 0 and set this to the back to the place in memory, where `aUsersBetted['1337']` points to.

Comment: @Purixi not a prolem at all. I am glad that I helped :)

Answer (score 0):

First, initiate your object value to 0. You are trying to add `200000` to an undefined value.

```
var aUsersBetted = {};
aUsersBetted['1337'] = 0;
aUsersBetted['1337'] += 200000;
window.console.log(aUsersBetted['1337']);
```

test it here: https://jsfiddle.net/hjqvwfwt/

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialized the variable aUsersBetted['1337'].

JavaScript tries to do this: **undefined+200000**

What you want: **0+200000**

**Use:**

```
aUsersBetted['1337'] = 0;
aUsersBetted['1337'] += 200000;
```